# How to flip div on clicking button instead of element itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to flip the element on clicking the button, but right now i am able to flip the element when i click on element itself. how can can i do the same but when i click on flip button.

Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          $(".card").flip({
            trigger: "click"
          });
        });
    </script>
```

html:

```
<div class="card"></div>

<button class="click">Flip</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add an event listener to the button:

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    $(".card").flip();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `trigger` to `manual`. Then you can call `flip(true)` or `flip(false)` on it. Try this:

```
$(".card").flip({
    trigger: 'manual'
});

$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.card').flip(true);
});
```

See the last example in the [demos](http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/) for more information.